# Complex contour integral Evaluation

Tags: integration

Use a complex contour integral to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2} \, dx$$

where $a>0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here's a MathJax Tutorial !](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Take note that this is not a "solve my homework" site, so it would be good containing your thoughts regarding the solution, each time you ask a question. Since it was your first time though and this is a common but tricky complex integration exercise, I decided to provide you with a solution, but left you with a bit of work for the Residue !

Comment: It it's $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2} \, da,$ then evaluating it is really simple. If it's $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2} \, dx,$ then it's more involved. But you wrote neither of those. I took the liberty of adding $dx. \qquad$

Comment: See my post on how to evaluate this type of integrals:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820349/fourier-transform-of-a-rational-function-using-contour-integration

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\Im\{e^{ix}\}}{x^2+a^2}dx = \Im \Bigg\{ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dx \Bigg\} $$

The singularities of the integrating function :

$$f(x) = \frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}$$

come as : $x^2 + a^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x= \pm i a$ since $a>0$.

But we're integrating over the bounds $0$ and $\infty$, which means we come upon only $x= ia$.

We will integrate the function $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, over the partially smooth curve that is consisted of the half-moon of the upper level of $γ_R$, with $z(θ) = Re^{iθ}$, $0 \geq θ \geq π$ and the line segment $[-R,R]$, where we take $R$ to be big enough, so that the singularity point $x=ia$ is inside $γ_R$.

From the ***Residue-Theorem*** we have :

$$\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dx + \int_{γ_R}\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}dz= 2\pi iRes(f(z),ia)  $$

The function also satisfies ***Jordan's Lemma***, so it is :

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{γ_R}\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}dz=0$$

thus :

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dx = \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dx =2πiRes(f(z),ia)$$

and finally :

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx = \Im \Bigg\{ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dx \Bigg\} = \frac{πe^{-a}}{2}$$

I'll leave the calculation of the residue : $Res(f(z),ia)$ to you.